# Get the storage space usage of multiple directories

Tags: powershell

I want to get the total volume in gigabytes of all the files in multiple directories using PowerShell.

eg all the files in `C:\MyDir1\`, `C:\MyDir2\` & `C:\MyDir3\` but not in other directories.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
$Folders = 'C:\MyDir1\','C:\MyDir2\','C:\MyDir3\'

"{0:N2} GB" -f ((Get-ChildItem $Folders -Recurse | Measure-Object -Property Length -Sum).Sum / 1GB)
```

`Get-ChildItem` accepts an array of strings as input for it's -Path parameter, so you can just define your list of paths as an array and then send this to that Parameter.

Then you use `Measure-Object` to return the `-Sum` of the `.Length` property of those items (which contains the size) and then divide that by `1GB` to convert that value to gigabytes.

The result is represented within the `"{0:N2} GB"` string via the `-f` (format) operator. the `:N2` part of this string rounds the result to two decimal places (so remove or change this if this isn't what you want). If you want a numeric value returned rather than a string result, simply remove this part.

Comment: The size should be in gigabytes. That's what the op has asked for! :)